# How to do interrupted time series analysis using R's plm?

Tags: r, lme4, panel-data, plm, nlme

I am trying to model the following interrupted time series model:

```
y = b0 + b1*time + b2*event + b3*time_since_event
```

The data, however, is nested inside users (id). Currently, I have the following nlme model specification:

```
m = lme(y ~ time + event + time_since_event, random=~1+time|id, correlation = corAR1(), data=df)
```

Is the above model possible in plm at all? I tried the following:

```
m = plm(
+   y ~ time + event + time_since_event,
+   data = pd_df,
+   model = 'within',
+   effect = 'twoways'
+ )
```

But it throws the following error:

```
Error in plm.fit(data, model, effect, random.method, random.models, random.dfcor,  (r_v1.R#361): empty model
Show stack trace
```

Not sure if I `plm` is not suited for interrupted time series analysis like the one mentioned [here](https://ds4ps.org/pe4ps-textbook/docs/p-020-time-series.html).

Comment: Any sample data to reproduce the error at our end?

Comment: please write ```dput(your dataframe)```and copy and paste it above. Alternatively, use pastebin, or make a mock dataset for us to use, otherwise we can't help you